# Changing the style of this react component in CSS to show the line numbers

Tags: css, reactjs, json, typescript, npm

I have implemented a react npm package called ["react-json-pretty"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-pretty) in a web interface,
I would like for it to show the line numbers next to each line like so:

[Not what I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FPq7.png)

[What I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEaIP.png)

The npm package allows for css modifications (see bottom of the [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-pretty))

I would like to mix the react-json-pretty with a CSS counter
[like this](https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/mdmmdQB)

I have tried to modify it and can't figure out a way to do this, does anyone know how this is possible ?

`Thanks`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Pretty much everything (with the skills I have) haha, I have tried to add the code in the code.io link inside the CSS file while naming it the same way as is done in the react-json-pretty package and I havent gotten it to work thus far !

Comment: Please add what you tried to the question itself :)

Comment: I don't know how to explain what I have done exept just say that I have put the [line counter code](https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/mdmmdQB) inside the CSS file that has [the code at the bottom of this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-pretty)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.